# Tried to merge branches, then tried to rebase - still can't force master to be identical to dev branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-merge, git-rebase

I've been trying to merge my dev branch into the master branch but as this is my first time, I think I've completely misunderstood the terminology.

**First, I tried a merge:**

I tried to merge dev into master which didn't work. When resolving conflicts, I used "ours" thinking this meant merging "my" dev branch into the master but while things changed, the site didn't look the same as it did when the dev branch was checkout.

**Then I tried a rebase:**

I then rather recklessly tried a rebase thinking this would force the master branch to be identical to the dev branch but again, possible used the wrong options to resolve the conflicts as the site looks the same as it did after the initial merge.

**At this point, can I force the master branch to be the same as the dev branch?**

If I switch back to the dev branch the site looks correct - how do you merge the changes into the master branch so the site looks the same as when the dev branch is checked out?

Or at this point, is there a way just to force master to be the same as dev?

Sorry if this is easy, I find the terminology in git confusing and seemingly didn't understand the answers/tutorials I've read - any help would be much appreciated.

BTW, I'm using the Mac Git client, Tower.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "force the master to be the same as the dev", the procedure which will always work is to:

- Delete the master branch (`git checkout dev; git branch -D master`)
- Recreate the master branch from dev (`git branch master; git checkout master`)

... Now the two branches are identical (same `HEAD` and thus same history).

Your problem is likely that you didn't reset after your botched merge. In theory, either a rebase (with a common ancestor) or a merge will produce a branch which integrates changes from both branches. If the merge doesn't go as you hoped, reset back to before it and try again. Don't commit the result until you're happy with it!

Comment: Thanks heaps! So after botching the first merge, I should've reset it - and the rebase didn't work because the botched merge created common ancestry between the two branches. So to fix things, I need to do what you suggested which makes sense - but what did I do wrong when I did the first merge (your best guess is all good!).

Comment: If you were in master, trying to merge dev and you selected "ours" you were selecting the changes from master, not dev.  Dev would have been "theirs."  After noting the merge did not look right, you could have done a `git reset --hard <commit before merge>` to reset things back to the state they were before the merge.

Comment: @Borealid - Your suggestion worked great for the local repo thanks. But when I try to push master back to github, I get an error that the tip of the current branch is behind and suggests merging the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull'). So if I git pull, I would want to use "ours" to resolves conflicts right? Or is it not as simple as that?

Comment: @CMSCSS When you're doing a merge, you really want to use a merge tool. The reason there's a conflict is because there are changes on *both* sides to the same area. If you use "ours" or "theirs", you'll lose one of the sets of changes. What you really want to do is pull and then "git mergetool" to merge the conflicting changes together before "git commit"ing the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Mac client but I've been using the git client for windows/linux and the plugin from eclipse and they all have an option to force an update.

If you do a push with a graphic interface, an option should come up, otherwise you surely need to add in option in a command line.

But before a harsh force update, have you tried this :

-Commit your changes

-Pull from the master branch

-Use the merge tool, in eclipse you can also compare your branch from an other upstream.
Once your conflicts are solved, add again all your files `git add .`

-Commit again !

-Push your branch to the master branch

Hopefully someone who knows Tower can help you more !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I want the changes from the dev branch, why would I PULL from master - wouldn't I want to PULL from dev?

Comment: well from what i understood, you want to merge the dev branch (on your local machine) into the master branch (on the git server), so you need to pull the master branch to check any conflicts and eventually solves them. You always need at first to pull the branch that you want to push into.

Comment: a very good tutorial for GIT : http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html#mergeconflict