# Local Git merge and rebase issues and github - totally confused sorry

Tags: git, github, merge

So I had the issues described here and followed instructions to delete master and create a new branch based off dev to solve my issue: [Tried to merge branches, then tried to rebase - still can't force master to be identical to dev branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146949/tried-to-merge-branches-then-tried-to-rebase-still-cant-force-master-to-be-i)

Now I'm trying to push the new master to github but get errors saying that the tip of the current branch is behind and suggests merging the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') - this makes sense to me but I don't understand how to force the remote master to be the same as my local one - hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to force the remote master to match yours you can do this:

```
git push --force origin master
```

**However** you will lose any history in the remote master that is not in your local master. Additionally if anyone else has pulled code from this Github repository they will run into significant trouble the next time they pull.

Comment: OK, so how should I fix this? Something that sounds reasonably straight forward has turned out to be totally confusing in reality sorry.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing a lot of context. If this is a private project that only you work on right now and it just happens to be up on Github then it may be okay to just run the command in my answer.